# Parameter error in Dymola Command "simulateMultiResultsModel"

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to link a dymola simulation file to python using the dymola-python interface. In the documentation
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Dymola%202023/Modelica/Library/python_interface/doc/dymola_interface.html
, the command simulateMultiResultsModel is described with the following example execution within Dymola command window:

(ok, traj) = simulateMultiResultsModel("Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches", stopTime=1.2, numberOfIntervals=10, resultFile="CoupleCluches", initialNames={"freqHz"}, initialValues=[0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4], resultNames={"J1.w","J3.w"});

This command varies the "freqHz" parameter and reads the results J1.w and J2.w

My problem is, i am getting the following error during the execution of command:

[image]

Warning: freqHz is not a settable parameter after translation

Im using Dymola2023 and this problem is within Dymola and has nothing to do with the Python Interface

I tried to use the example out of the documentation and was expecting a smooth excecution

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem and it was much easier than i thought. I overlooked the fact that in the code, freqHz is defined as f. The Documentation was outdated

Comment: The documentation will be improved for a coming Dymola release.